# How to subtract object values and add result to a new property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array of objects like this

```
const arr = [
  {time: '21/1/1998', sold: 8848},
  {time: '21/1/1997', sold: 8804},
  {time: '21/1/1996', sold: 8756},
  {time: '21/1/1995', sold: 8732},
  {time: '21/1/1994', sold: 8691},
  {time: '21/1/1993', sold: 8620},
  {time: '21/1/1992', sold: 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1991', sold: 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1990', sold: 8498},
];
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to subtract sold values `first - second`, `second - third`, `third - fourth` etc, and add that value to the new property called `soldInPeriod` and the last one should be 0.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
const arr = [
  {time: '21/1/1998', sold: 8848, soldInPeriod: 44},
  {time: '21/1/1997', sold: 8804, soldInPeriod: 48},
  {time: '21/1/1996', sold: 8756, soldInPeriod: 24},
  {time: '21/1/1995', sold: 8732, soldInPeriod: 41},
  {time: '21/1/1994', sold: 8691, soldInPeriod: 71},
  {time: '21/1/1993', sold: 8620, soldInPeriod: 109},
  {time: '21/1/1992', sold: 8511, soldInPeriod: 0},
  {time: '21/1/1991', sold: 8511, soldInPeriod: 13},
  {time: '21/1/1990', sold: 8498, soldInPeriod: 0},
];
```

I've tried to achieve this by using reduce

```
const newArr = Object.values(arr.reduce(function(r, { time, sold }) {
    r[sold] = r[sold] || {time, sold, soldInPeriod: 0 };
    console.log(sold)
    r[sold].soldInPeriod = r[sold].sold - sold;
    return r;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(newArr)
```

but this is not what I want because `soldInPeriod` is always 0. How can I do this? Any example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply map over the array and get the next object with the index and subtract the value.

```js
const arr = [
  { time: "21/1/1998", sold: 8848 },
  { time: "21/1/1997", sold: 8804 },
  { time: "21/1/1996", sold: 8756 },
  { time: "21/1/1995", sold: 8732 },
  { time: "21/1/1994", sold: 8691 },
  { time: "21/1/1993", sold: 8620 },
  { time: "21/1/1992", sold: 8511 },
  { time: "21/1/1991", sold: 8511 },
  { time: "21/1/1990", sold: 8498 },
];

const result = arr.map((obj, i, srcArray) => {
  return { ...obj, soldInPeriod: obj.sold - srcArray[i + 1]?.sold || 0 };
});

console.log(result);
```

Using one-liner syntax

```
const result = arr.map((obj, i, srcArray) => ({ ...obj, soldInPeriod: obj.sold - srcArray[i + 1]?.sold || 0 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array map method:

```js
arr.map((item, idx, src) => {
    if (idx === arr.length - 1)
        item.soldInPeriod = 0
    else
        item.soldInPeriod = item.sold - src[idx+1].sold;

    return item;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for(let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i].soldInPeriod = arr[i].sold - arr[i+1]?.sold || 0
}
```

You can also use **ForEach** loop just to simplify it a bit more.

```
arr.forEach((item,index) => {
    item.soldInPeriod = item.sold - arr[index+1]?.sold || 0
})
```